# ubuntu 22.04, pipewire, bluetooth audio output

Tags: bluetooth, pipewire

after update can not output audio through blue tooth. devices connect and show connected in bt manager, but does not show in audio settings. update, restart etc. does not help. maybe some problem with the last firmware update.

Comment: Have you tried to unpair and pair again? If so what were the results?

Comment: yes, pair, re-pair, reboot, trust, un-trust, nothing seems to work. I have had issues with pipewire and bt devices before. the device shows connected but will not output through that device --> disconnect, reconnect multiple times will get it to work. lately it has been working great, turn on the device, automatically shifts the output to that device. but seems a couple days ago something happened after an update, now the computer will not output to a bt device. does not show up in sound settings but shows in bt devices as connected. tks for the reply, appreciate